# How to find original and discount price difference of product in selenium webdriver

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to find out the difference between original and discounted price of any product on ecommerce site. Could you please suggest me how to calculate it ?
 Html code for price is as below :

```
 <html>
<ul class="pricing ng-scope" ng-if="activeColour.colourCode == '133290-LT-GREY'">
    <li class="price previous">
    <del>£99</del>
    </li>
    <li class="price unit">£69</li>
    </ul>
<html>
```

==============================================
code to find out product whose price difference is greater than 50 and add that product to cart

```
Actions act=new Actions(driver);
WebElement Category=driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='categories_nav']/li[1]/a"));
       WebElement Sales_clothng=driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='categories_nav']/li[1]/nav/div[1]/div[3]/ul[1]/li[3]/a"));
         act.moveToElement(Category).moveToElement(Sales_clothng).click().build().perform();
       Thread.sleep(2000);
          List<WebElement> Product_list=driver.findElements(By.xpath(".//*[@class='name']"));
                for (WebElement items_product : Product_list)
        {
            System.out.println(items_product.getText());

            }
       System.out.println("Originanal Price of items");
       List<WebElement> Original_price=driver.findElements(By.xpath(".//*[@class='price previous']"));
       System.out.println(Original_price.size());
          for(int i=0;i<Original_price.size();i++)
       {
               List<String> Original_price_lst = new ArrayList<String>();
           Original_price_lst.add(Original_price.get(i).getText());
           System.out.println(Original_price.get(i).getText());
             }
          System.out.println("Discounted Price of items");
       List<WebElement> Discounted_price=driver.findElements(By.xpath(".//*[@class='price unit']"));
       System.out.println(Discounted_price.size());
       for(int i=0;i<Original_price.size();i++)
       {
               List<String> Discounted_price_lst = new ArrayList<String>();
           Discounted_price_lst.add(Discounted_price.get(i).getText());
           System.out.println(Discounted_price.get(i).getText());
       }
      for(int i=0;i<Discounted_price.size();i++)
      {
          List<String> Original_price_lst_1 = new ArrayList<String>();
          List<String> Discounted_price_lst_1 = new ArrayList<String>();
          String original_price_removecurrencysymbol = Original_price.get(i).getText().substring(1,Original_price.get(i).getText().length());
           String discount_price_removecurrencysymbol = Discounted_price.get(i).getText().substring(1,Discounted_price.get(i).getText().length());
          System.out.println(original_price_removecurrencysymbol);
          System.out.println(discount_price_removecurrencysymbol);
          int difference = Integer.parseInt(original_price_removecurrencysymbol) -Integer.parseInt(discount_price_removecurrencysymbol);
            System.out.println("Difference is:"+difference);
                    if(difference>=50)
            {
                        driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@class='name']")).click();
                         driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[contains(@class,'add_to_cart')]")).click();
            }
      }
            }       
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Working code:

```
        WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        driver.get("http://www.tedbaker.com/uk/Womens/Sale/Accessories/Bags/c/sale_bags");

        String original_price = driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='content']/div/div[4]/div[2]/div[2]/article/div[2]/header/div/ul/li[1]/del")).getText();
        String discount_price = driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='content']/div/div[4]/div[2]/div[2]/article/div[2]/header/div/ul/li[2]")).getText();

        System.out.println(original_price);
        System.out.println(discount_price);

        String original_price_removecurrencysymbol = original_price.substring(1,original_price.length());
        String discount_price_removecurrencysymbol = discount_price.substring(1,discount_price.length());

        System.out.println(original_price_removecurrencysymbol);
        System.out.println(discount_price_removecurrencysymbol);

        int difference = Integer.parseInt(original_price_removecurrencysymbol) -Integer.parseInt(discount_price_removecurrencysymbol);

        System.out.println("Difference is:"+difference);
```

Comment: Thanks rakesh,one more question if i want to select only one product whose price difference is 30 from all avaliable product on the page .Then ,how to calculate it.

Comment: For that,you have to loop through all the products in the page,calculate their difference and store them in an array/list.then you can find the price which is greater than 30.Hope this helps!

Also you can upvote the answer if it helps !  :)

Comment: i have tried with below code, please find out the code inquestion section

Comment: how to customise xpath for below html code>><h4 class="name">
<a href="/uk/Womens/Gifts/Gifts-For-Her/WOU-Persian-Blue-flip-flop-and-shopper-bag-set-Navy/p/136505-NAVY?plpSlots=1" ng-href="/uk/Womens/Gifts/Gifts-For-Her/WOU-Persian-Blue-flip-flop-and-shopper-bag-set-Navy/p/136505-NAVY?plpSlots=1">WOU</a>
</h4>

Answer (score 0):

Fetch the price i.e original and discount in separate variables and convert them to integer.You also need to remove the currency symbol before converting to integer.Now you can subtract both of them to get the difference.

Comment: how fetch it , i am not able to find out it.

Comment: Share the url of the website.

Comment: Site >>http://www.tedbaker.com/uk/Womens/Sale/Accessories/Bags/c/sale_bags

Answer (score 0):

One liner.

```
 int diff =Integer.parseInt(driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='content']/div/div[4]/div[2]/div[2]/article/div[2]/header/div/ul/li[1]/del")).getText().substr(1))-Integer.parseInt(driver.findElement(By.className("price unit").getText()substr(1)));
```